# Using "that" in the sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammar

*In the following sentence using the word "**that**" is correct or it is better to remove it?*

> I did not think the motion of water that would follow certain physical relationships

Comment: Hello, vahid. Without 'that', this is very poor. With 'that' as written, it's ungrammatical.

Comment: It makes no sense as written, and is ungrammatical. Without "that" it appears to be grammatical but meaningless. What is it that you are trying to say?

Comment: this is my whole sentence: Those days, I only saw the calm or roaring appearance of water and I did not think the motion of water that would follow certain physical relationships.

Comment: This is the bit that makes no sense to me: "I did not think the motion of water that would follow certain physical relationships".

Comment: I want to say those days I do not know the flow of water has a certain physical relationship

Comment: I say that because physical equations govern fluid flow

Comment: how about this one, do you think this sentence is good: "I did not think the motion of water follows certain physical relationships"

Comment: I think what you're trying to say is: I did not know then that the motion of water follows certain physical relationships.  (or, instead of follows, "is governed by"; physical relationships means probably law of physics

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to remove "that" because it would be grammatically incorrect otherwise.

> I did not think the motion of water **<strike>that</strike>** would follow certain physical relationships

Say you're writing a paper for science. As long as you elaborate on which "physical relationships" the water's motion is following, the revised sentence is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

Don't remove it. Move it.

> I did not think that the motion of water would follow certain physical
>   relationships.

The intent of the sentence remains unclear.

Comment: Do you think this sentence has a clear meaning? I did not think that the motion of water follows certain physical relationships.